# MSSQL PIVOT - Incorrect syntax. Expecting ID or QUOTED_ID

Tags: sql-server, pivot

The following code

```
select orgUnitNum,  [2020-12-25], [2020-12-26], [2020-12-27], [2020-12-28], [2020-12-29], [2020-12-30], [2020-12-31], [2021-01-01] 
FROM (select * from @myTable) as source 
PIVOT (
    max(logincount)
    FOR [logindate] IN ( [2020-12-25], [2020-12-26], [2020-12-27], [2020-12-28], [2020-12-29], [2020-12-30], [2020-12-31], [2021-01-01])
) as pivot;
```

is producing the following error :

> Incorrect syntax near 'pivot'.  Expecting ID, or QUOTED_ID.

By all good will, I dont see any syntax error there.

Can you spot anything?

Comment: This is why using [Reserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for object names/aliases is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second 'pivot' that you're using as a table alias is the problem.  Should be using a non-keyword as the table alias, or delimiting it as `[pivot]`.

```
select orgUnitNum,  [2020-12-25], [2020-12-26], [2020-12-27], [2020-12-28], [2020-12-29], [2020-12-30], [2020-12-31], [2021-01-01] 
FROM (select * from @myTable) as source 
PIVOT (
    max(logincount)
    FOR [logindate] IN ( [2020-12-25], [2020-12-26], [2020-12-27], [2020-12-28], [2020-12-29], [2020-12-30], [2020-12-31], [2021-01-01])
) as pivoted;
```